# UI Button image disappears when “debug executable” is unchecked in edit scheme

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have created a UIButton in storyboard, and have set an image for the UIButton (the image is in assets.xcassets). The button shows up in the simulator and when run on an iPhone. However, if I quit the app on the iPhone and open it again, the button disappears, but I am still able to click it and it works. The same thing happens when I uncheck "debug executable." When I check the view hierarchy, the button is on top of the hierarchy but is invisible. Using `infoButton.isHidden = false` also does not work. In my button's view controller, I have called `view.bringSubviewToFront(_: infoButton)` in `viewDidLoad()`.

I have also tried setting the button's image programmatically, but it still doesn't show up. However, when I set a background color for the button with `infoButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue`, I can see a blue box where the button should be, but no image. Here are my settings
([part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nP8z.png),[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxgEf.png)) for the UIButton.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you set the Alpha value to 1 (img part2)? Does the same thing happen with a different image? Check the naming of the original image file you added to assets.xcassets, sometimes it happens that the image doesn't show if the name has a weird form or weird characters

Comment: I tried setting the alpha to 1 and setting the button's image programmatically, but neither worked. The image I'm using in assets.xcassets is just "info," which is a png, but setting the button's image to "info" or "info.png" made no difference. I don't think it's an image name issue, since the image appears on initial build, but disappears if I quit the app and open it again.

Comment: could you share your source code? or if you can’t maybe you could create a sample project where this issue is reproducible